# How to use maven-m2e-codestyle connector?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

According to https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-3293 "Maven m2e Code-Style and Save-Actions connector"

> This plugin is executed inside m2e Eclipse plugin when the project is
>   configured and configures the save-actions and code-styling options of
>   your maven project so you don't need to commit the .settings files to
>   your repo

I have not been able to find a sample showing how this connector is supposed to be used. What do I put into my pom.xml to trigger it, how do I know if my eclipse installation has the connector installed?

Does anyone have an example configuration for this connector?

Comment: how do you even install the plugin?  It's not in discovery.

Comment: I actually created a rewrite of this plugin https://github.com/trajano/m2e-codestyle-maven-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the source code, it's something like:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.despegar.maven.plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-m2e-codestyle</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>configure</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <codeStyleBaseUrl>http://some/path/to/eclipse/files/</codeStyleBaseUrl>
        <!-- Will not work. Scheme 'file' not registered. -->
        <!-- <codeStyleBaseUrl>file://localhost/some/path/to/eclipse/files/</codeStyleBaseUrl> -->
        <baseDir>${basedir}/</baseDir>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The 2 configuration parameters are:

- `<codeStyleBaseUrl>`
- `<baseDir>`

It copies these 3 files:

```
${codeStyleBaseUrl}/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
${codeStyleBaseUrl}/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
${codeStyleBaseUrl}/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs
```

to:

```
${baseDir}/.settings/
```

Note that `<codeStyleBaseUrl>` must be http/https since it uses HttpClient behind the scenes.